# Michael Hartl Chapter9 (Authorization) Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Authentication test generating errors which i'm unable to understand.
it says unit test assertion error.

```
Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `assertions' for #<RSpec::Rails::TestUnitAssertionAdapter::AssertionDelegator:0xba527604>
```

authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
 describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

user_controller.rb

The authorization application code uses a before filter, which uses the before_action command to arrange for a particular method to be called before the given actions. (The command for before filters used to be called before_filter, but the Rails core team decided to rename it to emphasize that the filter takes place before particular controller actions.) To require users to be signed in, we define a signed_in_user method and invoke it using before_action :signed_in_user, as shown in

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this line below to your gem file,and remove the older "rspec-rails" line from your gem file.

```
gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.14.0.rc1'
```

then run these commands,

```
$ bundle update

$ bundle install
```

then again check for the test.

Comment: Thank you, I was really stuck with the same problem and your solution worked for me! +1